# Transform "4CA2CACA" to "CCCCACCACA"

Tags: python, python-re

I have already tried this (as somebody told me on another question):

```
 import re

 def decode(txt):
     list = []
     for cnt, char in re.findall(r"([\d*])([^d])", txt):
         list.extend((char * (int(cnt) if cnt else 1)))
     list = "".join(list)
     return list
```

Example:

```
print(decode("2CACA2CACA3CACACA3CAC"))
```

This is what I get

```
CCCCCCCCCC
```

And this is what I need

```
CCACACCACACCCACACACCCAC
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to do it without any imports, then you could do something like this:

```
x = '2CACA2CACA3CACACA3CAC0M'
int_string = ""
char_list = []
for char in x:
    if char.isnumeric():
        int_string += char
        continue
    else:
        if not int_string:
            char_list.append(char)
        else:
            char_list.append(char * int(int_string))
        int_string = ""
print("".join(char_list))
```

This will work for any positive integers, even zero, as you can see in the above example.

Comment: how can i make it so it works for numbers between 1-99?

Comment: @vanquish I made a different version that work a bit differently, but still doesn't use any imports, which also works for any numbers, including zero. See the edit on the post.

Comment: The `continue` is extraneous as  control flow will naturally go to the next loop iteration anyway.

Comment: @Chris I would argue that the `else` needs to go, and the `continue` stay. Although, the whole thing could go, cause you can do this with regex in one line.

Answer (score 2):

`re.sub` can take a named function or lambda as its second argument, and you can use this to accomplish your goal. Using this approach you simply don't do any substitution when a letter does not have a number in front of it.

```
def decode(s):
  return re.sub(r'(\d+)([a-zA-Z])', 
                lambda m: m.group(2)*int(m.group(1)), 
                s)

decode("2CACA2CACA3CACACA3CAC")
# 'CCACACCACACCCACACACCCAC'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is characters without a digit in front. This will include those:

```py
import re

def decode(txt):
    _list = []
    for cnt, char, single_char in re.findall(r"(\d)([^\d])|([^\d])", txt):
        if single_char:
            _list.extend(single_char)
        else:
            _list.extend((char * (int(cnt) if cnt else 1)))
    _list = "".join(_list)
    return _list

print(decode("2CACA2CACA3CACACA3CAC"))
```